# Is it possible to partition $\mathbb R^3$ into unit circles?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, circle-packing

Is it possible to partition $\mathbb R^3$ into unit circles?

Comment: I know how to do it with smooth circles.  Maybe 15 years ago some Hopkins student (I forget his name, he is Canadian) mentioned he knew how to do it with round circles.  But I don't think he ever described the construction to me.  I'm curious why you're interested in this question? 

Comment: What's the difference between a smooth circle and a round circle?


Comment: A smooth circle is just a smooth compact connected 1-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$, i.e. the image of a smooth non-constant periodic function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$.  Round means having constant curvature and zero torsion, also there's the equivalent definition of O'Rourke's, in the comments to his answer below.

Comment: See related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21327/is-it-still-impossible-to-partition-the-plane-into-jordan-curves-without-choice

Comment: Ryan, it was given to me as an exercise. I've spent many hours trying to solve it. Now I understand I was supposed to use the axiom of choice, which I actually tried; presumably not hard enough.

Comment: What is the motivation of this question?

Comment: @Ryan I might be the Canadian you are remembering.  The solution I know using round circles is the one described by Spencer below, and I learned it from Danny Arnon, who was a student of Mike Hopkins at the time.

Comment: J.H. Conway and H.T. Croft proved that 3-space can be partitioned into congruent geometric circles, using the axiom of choice (Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society , Volume 60 , Issue 4 , October 1964). I have shown that for a continuous foliation of a connected open set U of 3-space by congruent geometric circles, there is a finite upper bound on the volume of such a U. (Forthcoming in a joint paper.)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The construction is based on a well ordering of $R^3$ into the least ordinal of cardinality continuum. Let $\phi$ be that ordinal and let $R^3=\{p_\alpha:\alpha<\phi\}$ be an enumeration of the points of space. We define a unit circle $C_\alpha$ containing $p_\alpha$ by transfinite recursion on $\alpha$, for some $\alpha$ we do nothing. Here is the recursion step. Assume we have reached step $\alpha$ and some circles $\{C_\beta:\beta<\alpha\}$ have been determined. If some of them contains (=covers) $p_\alpha$, we do nothing. Otherwise, we choose a unit circle containing $p_\alpha$ that misses all the earlier circles. For that, we first choose a plane through $p_\alpha$ that is distinct from the planes of the earlier circles. This is possible, as there are continuum many planes through $p_\alpha$ and less than continuum many planes which are the planes of those earlier circles. Let $K$ be the plane chosen. The earlier circles intersect $K$ in less than continuum many points, so it suffices to find, in $K$, a unit circle going through $p_\alpha$ which misses certain less than continuum many points. That is easy: there are continuum many unit circles in $K$ that pass through $p_\alpha$ and each of the bad points disqualifies only 2 of them.

Comment: I understand your solution (provided I believe that there's such a well ordering). A little bit disappointed, but thank you!

Answer (score 53):

Even though this question is old, I'd like to give what I regard as a very beautiful solution.  It is different from the others in that the circles used are not round (but they are unlinked).  First observe that the circles $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, $z = c$, for $r \geq 1$ and $c$ any real number, decompose all of $\Bbb{R}^3$ except an open cylinder into circles.  At first glance, this seems to have accomplished nothing, since the open cylinder is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^3$, so we have reduced the original problem to an equivalent problem.  However, look at the left-hand figure of the included image, which shows an open cylinder embedded as a U shape, with the ends going to infinity in the same direction.  Since this is just a deformation of the original embedding, we can decompose the complement into circles.  To handle the interior, embed an open cylinder into it, as shown in the right-hand figure.  We can decompose the complement of the smaller U-shaped cylinder into circles.  We continue in this way, making sure that the embedded cylinders go off to infinity, so that every point of $\Bbb{R}^3$ is included at some finite stage.

It seems like we have never really solved the problem, but instead have just pushed it away so much that it vanishes into thin air!

[image: embedded cylinders]

Comment: @Dan: welcome to mathoverflow!

Comment: This (generalized) proof appears in the short 1985 paper *"Topological partitions of Euclidean space by spheres"* (by Bankston & Fox) for partitioning $\mathbb R^{n+2}$ by $S^n$, apparently due to S. Kakutani when $n=1$.

Comment: @ChrisGerig Thanks for the reference!  I heard that argument by word of mouth in the 90's, and it's good to know the source. This link pulls up the paper for me: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256840029_Topological_Partitions_of_Euclidean_Space_by_Spheres

Answer (score 32):

Péter's proof is very clever and, while there is no real need to resurrect this thread, the following is quite straightforward in case one is not inclined to hunt for it in the literature on this subject:

Observe that you can cover a two-punctured sphere with circles. Now consider a family of circles lying in the $xy$ plane, radii 1, centred at the points $(4k+1,0,0)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Each sphere about the origin intersects this family in exactly two places.

Comment: This is exactly the construction of Szulkin [MR0719756] (see my answer below).

Comment: But the question was about a partition into *unit* circles, and it's not obvious that an arbitrary two-punctured sphere can be covered with *unit* circles.

Answer (score 25):

In [this article](http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=77)<sup>1</sup>, the authors prove that not only can you partition $R^3$ into congruent circles, but you can do so into *unlinked* congruent circles. They also prove a variety of other similar results: $R^3$ can be partitioned into isometric copies of any family of continuum many real analytic curves. And they consider the question in higher dimensions, and also the role of AC in the proofs: for example, in $R^3$ no AC is needed for circles, if different sizes are allowed.

<sup>1</sup>M. Jonsson and J. Wästlund: Partition of $R^3$ into curves, Mathematica Scandinavica 83 (1998) 192-204; [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24493132), [author's website](http://www.math.chalmers.se/%7Ewastlund/)

Comment: Is it known if the axiom of choice is required for congruent circles to partition?

Comment: Ryan, I'm not sure. All the arguments I have heard use AC in this case, but I have never heard a proof that AC was required for such a thing (and it is difficult to see how such a proof would proceed). But perhas the geometers will come through with a positive construction...

Comment: The article is: http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/13850/11850

Comment: Regarding whether AC is required, or whether there is a Borel partition of the various types, I asked the following question: http://mathoverflow.net/q/93601/1946

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins : What paper is this? The links aren't working for me, and you didn't provide authors or a title or even a journal or year.

Comment: The paper is: PARTITIONS OF R^3 INTO CURVES, M. JONSSON and J. WAÎSTLUND, MATH. SCAND. 83 (1998), 192-204. The link works for me.

Answer (score 14):

A very nice, explicit, elementary partition (without the Axiom of Choice) of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into geometric circles of variable radii is given in: [MR0719756] Szulkin, Andrzej. $\mathbb{R}^3$ *is the union of disjoint circles*. Amer. Math. Monthly 90 (1983), no. 9, 640–641.

Answer (score 10):

Evelyn Sander says [here](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/forum/hoops_links/khoops.html), "Geometric circles of unit radius are called hoops. Using the Axiom of Choice, J.H. Conway and H.T. Croft showed that it is nevertheless possible to discontinuously fill three-space using disjoint hoops."  The "nevertheless" was to contrast with filling continuously. This was a report on a talk by Daniel Asimov in 1994, who showed that it is not possible to fill continuously with hoops.

Comment: Does "geometric" mean round with a fixed radius? 

Comment: @Ryan: Yes. "A geometric circle in $R^3$ is the set of points in a fixed plane that lie a fixed positive distance from a center point that lies in the same plane."

Comment: I mean, do all the circles have the same radius?  Certainly their centres and axis can vary.  

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Somehow I completely mis-read your answer.  It makes sense now and my comments were off-track.

Comment: I don't understand, didn't your original answer say something about "using algebraic topology it's possible to show..." ?


Comment: @Ryan: My fault, not yours! Initially I pasted in the wrong quote, and you must have read it in the one minute before I corrected!  Mea culpa!