# Can 4-space be partitioned into Klein bottles?

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, packing-and-covering, sphere-packing

It is known that $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be partitioned into disjoint circles,
or into disjoint unit circles, or into congruent copies of a real-analytic curve
([Is it possible to partition $\mathbb R^3$ into unit circles?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/28655/6094)).
But it has [recently been proved](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mobius-strips-defy-a-link-with-infinity-20190220/) that the same is not true of Möbius strips:

> Frolkina, Olga D. "Pairwise disjoint Moebius bands in space." *Journal of Knot Theory and Its Ramifications* 27, no. 09 (2018): 1842005.
>   [Journal link](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218216518420051).
>
> Melikhov, Sergey A. "A note on O. Frolkina's paper 'Pairwise disjoint Moebius bands in space'." [arXiv:1810.04089](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04089) (2018).

(The first paper proves it for tame subsets, the second removes the tame restriction.)
My question is:

> ***Q***. Does this new result imply that $\mathbb{R}^4$, or $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n \ge 5$, cannot be partitioned into [Klein bottles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle), congruent or otherwise?

---

[image: KlienBot]

          

<sup>Image from [Sensei's Library](https://senseis.xmp.net/?KleinBottle).</sup>

---