# $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the union of disjoint circles

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, gt.geometric-topology, ho.history-overview

In the question [Covering the space by disjoint unit circles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162324/covering-the-space-by-disjoint-unit-circles)
 the following result is attributed to Sierpinski.

> **Theorem.** The Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$ *is* a union of nondegenerate disjoint circles.

But the usual reference on this result is

*Szulkin, Andrzej*, [**$\mathbb{R}^ 3$ is the union of disjoint circles**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2323284), Amer. Math. Monthly. 90, 640-641 (1983). [ZBL0521.52011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0521.52011). [MR0719756](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=719756).

What is the correct reference? I failed to find this result among Sierpinski's works.

Comment: [Related post for who want to see various solutions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/28647/90655)

Comment: I think Sierpinski has proved a pure set-theoric theorem that this theorem is a corollary of it. Perhaps [this may helps but I am not sure](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/24/0/93217/sur-le-produit-combinatoire-de-deux-ensembles-jouissant-de-la-propriete-c). Also see abstract of [this chapter](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-0750-3_14) that is about $\Bbb R^2$ case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be correct. I was wrong, probably because this result appears in Ciesielski's book (*"Set theory for the working mathematician"* CUP, 1997; Theorem 6.1.3) near a result of Sierpinski. I corrected my question accordingly.