Is there a continuous partition of space into circles?
Question 1. Is there a continuous partition of space $\mathbb{R}^3$ into circles?
I strongly suspect not.
It is well-known by diverse arguments that space can be partitioned into circles. There is an elegant simple argument from the axiom of choice, which works generally with circles, ellipses, triangles, squares, and so forth, almost any kind of shape. One simply proceeds in a transfinite recursion, placing the next circle so as to hit a desired point, while avoiding the previous (fewer than continuum many) circles. (See the excellent article Jonsson, M.; Wästlund, J., Partitions of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into curves, Math. Scand. 83, No. 2, 192–204 (1998). ZBL0951.52018. JStor.) The argument can be modified to make the circles all of different radii, or all of the same radii, or realizing every radius exactly once, or making no two circles coplanar nor even in parallel planes, or making every circle come within 1 of the origin, and so forth. It is very flexible.
There are also explicit constructions that do not rely on the axiom of choice, producing a partition of space into circles. For example, see theorem 1.1 of the Jonsson-Wästlund article. It does remain open, however, how to achieve several of the further properties, such as all-circles-same-size, by an explicitly described partition.
Meanwhile, none of the explicit constructions that I know of are continuous, and I suspect that there is no continuous partition of space into circles.
A continuous partition of space into circles is a partition assigning to each point in space a circle, in such a way that the function mapping each point to the center of the corresponding circle and the line perpendicular is a continuous function. We do not need to give the circles an orientation.
I am here in Madison, having spoken at the seminar, and several of us (myself, Joe Miller, Steffen Lempp, Uri Andrews, Mariya Soskova) spent the afternoon discussing it.
We can prove that there is no continuous partition of space into circles, if there would be a pair of linked circles present. The reason is that if circles C and D are linked, then we can continuously deform circle C to any desired circle C', simply by following a path mapping any point of C to a point on C' and considering the circles that arise for the points on that path. All these continuous deformations of C will remain linked with D, and so C' is linked with D (and consequently, by also deforming D to any D', we see that any two circles are linked with each other). But now consider the points in the disc spanning D. The function mapping those points to the radius of the corresponding circle on which those points lie is continuous, and so it achieves a maximum by compactness. So none of the circles linked with D can reach points very far away, a contradiction.
The link-free case, however, remains unsettled.
Question 2. Is there a continuous partition of space $\mathbb{R}^3$ into loops?
That is, we weaken the requirements from geometric circles to topological circles. For the notion of continuity, we can say that two loops are close if they have parameterizations whose images remain always close.
Again, I suspect the answer is negative.
The linked case argument works just as well for topological circles, so the open case occurs when all loops are unlinked.

Please help me retag if appropriate.

I guess Borel & Serre’s Impossibilité de fibrer un espace euclidien par des fibres compactes should be relevant…

Your continuity requirement would force $\mathbb R^3$ to be a circle bundle, i.e. the total space of a bundle with fiber a circle, and it is not.

@RyanBudney Sorry, I don't really know what that means. Could you post an answer explaining the argument?

One quick observation is that if you consider the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e. $\mathbb{S}^3$), then Hopf fibration does the job.

@RyanBudney - when the parts of the partition are just continuous loops, how do you prove that the quotient space is an orbifold?

I have often wondered and chatted with people about the least complexity of a partition of $\Bbb R^3$ into circles (as a subspace of the Vietoris hyperspaces $K(\Bbb R^3)$). For example is there a Borel partition of the space into circles of unit radius? This is probably related to whether you can produce such a thing without AC. What is the least complexity a partition into circles of different sizes can have? One can ask many similar related questions

@AlessandroCodenotti Indeed, I asked exactly that question here on MathOverflow 12 years ago: https://mathoverflow.net/q/93601/1946. Can we prove there is no Borel partition of space into unit circles? And similarly for the other kinds of partitions. It still has no answer.

@JoelDavidHamkins I had not seen your question, but unfortunately it went unanswered... I think this kind of questions are extremely interesting

Related question  $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the union of disjoint circles. In particular it contains a link to the earlier article.

As a partial answer, there is no smooth partition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into smooth loops.  For, consider the quotient space; it is necessarily a two-orbifold (locally a surface, possibly having isolated points each having a neighbourhood modelled on $\mathbb{R}^2$ modulo a finite-order rotation).
Since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is non-compact and simply connected, so is the quotient.  The only such orbifold is $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Thus the partition gives $\mathbb{R}^3$ the structure of an $S^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Now, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible.  So any $S^1$-bundle over it is isomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2$.  This has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ and we are done.

Smoothness is not really necessary.  Instead we need that every loop has a small neighbourhood which is homeomorphic to a "standard fibering of a solid torus".  If this holds, then the partition gives $\mathbb{R}^3$ the structure of a Seifert fibered space.  The non-compact case is more difficult than the compact case, but there is still a rich theory.
The extra structure (of namely having good neighbourhoods) holds when the parts of the partition are (continuously varying) round circles.  So the answer to Question 1 is no. Question 2 feels more subtle; after all, continuous loops in space can be pretty badly behaved! So obtaining the bundle structure seems more difficult.

The actual result is that there is no topological foliation of $R^3$ whose leaves are topological circles. It is a consequence of a theorem to David Epstein that a topological foliation of a 3-manifold whose leaves are circles is Seifert.

@MoisheKohan - Which paper of Epstein's are you referring to?  His 1972 paper "Periodic flows on three-manifolds" needs (?) the foliation to be at least $C^1$, and needs the ambient space to be compact: see page 67.

Let me check, I might have misremembered.

Yes, I indeed misremembered. In fact, Vogt (1989 with improvement in 1993) constructed a topological foliation of $R^3$ by smooth circles (and proved similar results in higher dimensions).

If I’m not missing something, @Chris Schommer-Pries’ comment on Moishe Kohan’s answer combines with this answer to give a “no” to question 2 as well.  Chris’s comment points out: ‘[Vogt’s 1989 paper] notes “A compact foliation has a locally bounded volume-of-leaf function if and only if it is a Seifert fibration”. […] [This question’s] “close images” criterion for continuity surely implies a locally bounded volume-of-leaf function.’

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine That is what I thought, but now I am not sure. I read Moishe's response to my comment as saying that he isn't sure Vogt's claim there is justified. Vogt cites a paper of Epstein "Foliations with all leaves compact". If I am reading Epstein's paper correctly he shows an equivalence of "bounded volume-of-leaf" to several other conditions but this only includes a Seifert fibration if the foliation is further assumed to be C^1. Maybe this condition can be removed or relaxed? If not it looks like there is still room for a positive answer in the non-differentiable C^0 case.

Yes, there is a topological foliation of $\mathbb R^3$ by smooth circles. A foliation by topological circles was constructed in by Vogt in
Vogt, Elmar, A foliation of ${\mathbb{R}}^3$ and other punctured 3-manifolds by circles, Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. 69, 215-232 (1989). ZBL0688.57016.
In the subsequent paper he improved to the result, extending it to higher dimensions and getting smooth circles (but still, just a topological foliation):
Vogt, Elmar, Existence of foliations of Euclidean spaces with all leaves compact, Math. Ann. 296, No. 1, 159-178 (1993). ZBL0816.57018.
But these foliations correspond to decompositions of $\mathbb R^3$ which are not upper semicontinuous. There are no upper semicontinuous decompositions of  $\mathbb R^3$ in round circles, see
Cobb, John, Nice decompositions of (R^ n) entirely into nice sets are mostly impossible, Geom. Dedicata 62, No. 1, 107-114 (1996). ZBL0854.54015.

Is it clear that a foliation is continuous in the sense of this question?

Wait, does the word “circle” here refer to a submanifold diffeomorphic to $S^1$ or to a bona fide Euclidean circle (set of points on a plane at equal distance from a center point)? Because the question is about the latter, but Vogt's paper mentions circles in a manifold, which can only make sense in the former sense. (Maybe there's an argument to reduce one to the other, however. I don't see one.)

@WillSawin: I am addressing the 2nd question. The circles here are not round, of course.

@Gro-Tsen: I was addressing the 2nd question: circles are not round.

I know, but I'm referring to this condition: "For the notion of continuity, we can say that two loops are close if they have parameterizations whose images remain always close."

I don't think these Vogt foliations answer the question, but perhaps the question is a bit vague.

These foliations do not satisfy the continuity condition in the OP. In the introduction to the first of Vogt's papers mentioned he notes "A compact foliation has a locally bounded volume-of-leaf function if and only if it is a Seifert fibration". In particular the foliation he constructs does not have a locally bounded volume-of-leaf function. The "close images" criterion for continuity surely implies a locally bounded volume-of-leaf function.

@ChrisSchommer-Pries: Yes, I am aware of this and the penultimate paragraph of my answer says that these foliations are not upper semicontinuous, which is weaker than continuity. And, yes, I am aware of what Vogt says. However, at the moment I do not see how to justify Vogt's claim.
